# Removing marginTop of ListView with scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I want to start ListView with marginTop and with scrolling marginTop should be removed.
Here is my code:

```
<ListView
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: I believe this is easiest done if you add margin to first list item instead.

Comment: it does not work. @harism